# How to dock UWP application to screen edge?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am trying to Dock a UWP application on launch,to the right edge of my screen. In other words, Im launching my app in a preferred window size (full height and narrow width) - which is working. I am seeking help to programatically snap my App window to the right edge of the screen. The Windows 10 Snap Assist helps users manually do this- checking if this is possible programatically.

Answer (score 0):

> I am seeking help to programatically snap my App window to the right edge of the screen.

Unfortunately, currently there is no API can support this feature directly in UWP app. Only have APIs to get if the current window is in close proximity to the left or right edge of the screen. Details please reference `AdjacentToLeftDisplayEdge` and `AdjacentToRightDisplayEdge` properties of [`ApplicationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview) class.

If you still want this feature ,you can also submit this feature request to [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).